# Error while trying to start react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

[Error while trying to start myfirstreact using npm start]

Hi All,
I am new to react. I am trying to start myfirstreact using npm start, I am getting an error which is giving me a path to debug but, I am not able to understand the error.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: And what is the error? Please try to review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with the script you are trying to run and the error message you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Create-react-app? In the words of https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html (and they should know):

*Create React App is a comfortable environment for learning React, and is the best way to start building a new single-page application in React.*

It's one line of code to install it, and one line of code to create a working app that updates automatically at every save. And the code is more up to date than a lot of examples and tutorials you can find (uses functional programming, for example).